# Uso del "Bitwise" - Java

Tags: java

Me dicen "para encriptar un int cambie el bit #3 de 0 a 1 usando bitwise", Necesito una explicacion de este operador, No tengo idea de su sintaxis ni de como usarlo..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Buenas,

Los operadores `Bitwise` trabajan a nivel de bit, permitiendo cambiar los valores de bits específicos:

[Enlace de ejemplos](https://es.wikibooks.org/wiki/Programaci%C3%B3n_en_Java/Operadores_de_bits)

Ejemplo:

Vamos a usar por ejemplo el operador de Bitwise `~`:

Si tenemos `a = ~2` -> `a = -3`

Explicación:

El operador `~` invierte todos los bits del número que has puesto detrás, en este caso el 2 -> `0000 0010`

Si invertimos todos los bits del 2 nos queda lo siguiente: `1111 1101` que es `-3`

Espero que te sirva de ayuda.